# Can I have same blob storage in different regions with same name?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob storage with name DIDA in WEST US region. Can I create a same blob storage with same name in other regions? If not then, how can I implement this scenario?

Note : I need blob storage in different regions as I might have audience across the glob so to avoid network traffic delay.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable RA-GRS for this.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/general-availability-of-azure-read-access-geo-redundant-storage-ra-grs/

This will give you an extra endpoint for that secondary region with a -secondary postfix to the url.

Also have a look at this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/04/introducing-read-access-geo-replicated-storage-ra-grs-for-windows-azure-storage.aspx

But to answer your questions; the answer is no, you cannot have 2 with the same name.l

Another thing you may look at is using cname and dns to map to the correct region; ex you create blob dida-us and dida-asia. This becomes dida-us.core.windows.net or something like that; with DNS you can add a cname for uscdn.yourdomain.com and Asiacdn.yourdomain.com mapping to storage blob then based on the visitors geolocation you can use the appropriate url.  Or you can skip the cname and just use the azure blob urls.

If you stated what your setup was; maybe a clearer suggestion can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by “name”.  A storage account can only exist in a single region, but you can create multiple storage accounts, each with a different region if you like.  There is nothing stopping you from creating the same blob with the same blob name in both regions, but note that the fully qualified name of the blob includes the storage account, which would be different.  Thus, you could create two (or more) identical blobs with URIs that look like:

http://account1.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/DIDA   (in one region)
http://account2.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/DIDA   (in a second region)

If you want the URIs to actually be identical, you will need to use a CDN on top of Azure Storage.  RA-GRS is, in general, not a scalable solution for this scenario.